# knitr: entangle source and output in one listing

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm currently trying to use knitr to create a presentation where I want to include some R code chunks and the corresponding output.

When knitting an Rnw to a pdf document, is there an option to put the R output in the same chunk/lstlisting as the code?

I use knitr hooks to put source and output into an listing

```
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  paste("\\begin{lstlisting}",
        paste(x, collapse = "\n"),
        "\\end{lstlisting}",
        sep = "\n"
  )
}, output = function(x, options) {
    paste("\\begin{lstlisting}",
        paste(x, collapse = "\n"),
        "\\end{lstlisting}",
        sep = "\n"
  )
})
```

This results in:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Is there a way to put source and output into the same chunk?